# Reactivity in Vue JS to store all changes made?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js

I'm trying to store separate objects into one array, the issue is that I'm not sure how I can have the previous input stored as well - my data gets overwritten. I included a short recording of the issue that hopefully makes things clear: https://vimeo.com/306470918

and here's the fiddle of the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/h64wafkp/46/

I could push everything into an existing array, but that formats it all wrong and I'm stuck with an arrays-inside-an-array type of format which messes things up.. any idea how I can resolve the issue? I'd like to keep the format of

```
 [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "user_id": 2, // notice id is user 2
    "date": "2018-12-04",
    "duration": 10
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": 1, // another user id in the same array
    "date": "2018-12-13",
    "duration": 41
  },
]
```

and not

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "user_id": 1,
      "date": "2018-12-03",
      "duration": 13
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "user_id": 1,
      "date": "2018-12-02",
      "duration": 13
    },
  ]
]
```

If I do something like `Object.assign({}, object1, object2)`, that does not store everything in one big array but rather in one big object so I can't go with that either. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some of the code please? It's not easy to get everything from the videos. If you want to keep track of changes to the object mutations, that's one of the central features of [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) but that adds complexity

Comment: I did provide you with the fiddle

Comment: Ooops. I'm an idiot. Sorry, I'll check it out

Comment: which lines in your code that generate the issue?

Comment: the `setDuration` function, line 130

Comment: @erikvm but it seems work? so what is the undesired behavior ?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter yeah almost, the thing is I'd like to have everything stored in one array rather than each user having one array each because I need to send the data to my backend in one array. I did try with Object.assign but that doesn't cut it

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim well, no. I need all objects across all users to be stored in one array, not just the changes made on the latest user, does that make sense?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter if you check my first post, that is the array structure I need to achieve. (first code block). It's one array that contains all objects. I can't send the data to my backend otherwise..

Comment: @erikvm check this https://jsfiddle.net/L0fyj7ws/

Comment: That's awesome @BoussadjraBrahim, thanks a lot. Can that function be translated to only update the `savedHours` array, instead of the `users` array? (Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L0fyj7ws/1/)

edit: I just copied in an array of `savedHours` values, they are not tied to anything, but can I do the same function logic on that type of data structure?

Or I guess I can just extract the `hours` array itself from the function you created on `this.users`?

Comment: yes and i had changed `@input` to `@keyup.enter` check this https://jsfiddle.net/yL97eot0/ if it's right i will put as answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185287/discussion-between-erikvm-and-boussadjra-brahim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correct, you need to read all currently set hours into a single array. In your fiddle, you have the line `this.newHours = user.hours` at the very end, returning you only the current users' hours.

If you want to read all hours of all users, you need to sum them all up together - I'd suggest using `reduce`, resulting in this line:

```
this.newHours = this.users.reduce((hours, user) => [...hours, ...user.hours], []);
```

Adding a `4` into the input for 5th Dec for `nas`, it will result in:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 1,
    "date": "2018-12-03",
    "duration": 13
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "date": "2018-12-02",
    "duration": 13
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "user_id": 2,
    "date": "2018-12-04",
    "duration": 10
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": 2,
    "date": "2018-12-13",
    "duration": 41
  },
  {
    "user_id": 2,
    "date": "2018-12-05",
    "duration": "4"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve - only one thing - is it possible to only have the values that are added/changed? If my data base grows I don't wanna have to re-send all existing values for all users on each post request

Comment: In that case, I'd probably just save all changes in the `newHours` as a multi-dimensional object like `newHours[<user_id>][<date>] = duration` and then map this object back to the array you need for the server as soon as you save. Here is an updated version of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h64wafkp/92/

Comment: The problem with this is that if you add a new value to an existing input field (change the value in December 2 on row 1) - it won't save that actual ID, only the `user id` - that value already exists in the database and I need to still keep that id, if I change that specific value (december 2 on row 1) - it'll remove the `id` property.

The values that already exist in the table has an id property: https://imgur.com/a/vpTmE6U - that one I still need to retain

Comment: I've changed the fiddle according to your needs: https://jsfiddle.net/h64wafkp/96/ - It's saving everything it had before now and spreads the object into it again

Comment: Thanks a lot Narigo - really appreciate it!

Comment: Any chance you can explain how the `getChanges` method works? Not entirely sure with the nested reduce and spread operators..

Comment: I've updated the fiddle again and added a few comments. I hope they help :) https://jsfiddle.net/h64wafkp/100/

Comment: Thanks a ton! Truly grateful for this